# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar por aplicación con el comando cut y wc?

Tags: bash, unix, shell-script, procesamiento-de-texto, cut

Tengo una duda importante con respecto a los comandos de `cut` y `wc`.

Necesito saber cuántas líneas tienen nuestros programas en nuestro sistema, en total por aplicación.
La aplicación son los primeros 3 caracteres de cada programa.

Para conseguir eso, he hecho un script de shell en Linux, pero no funciona y no sé por qué.

Creo un archivo ordenado con una lista de nuestros artículos (algo como esto):

```
/aplic/DSNI/A06P065P.cot
/aplic/DSNI/A06R100.cot
/aplic/DSNI/A06T013.cot
/aplic/SISI/T00W500.cot
/aplic/SISI/Z22P1002.cot
/aplic/SISI/Z22P1003.cot
/aplic/SISI/Z22P750Z.cot
```

Y mi código es:

```
find /aplic/DSNI/ /aplic/SISI/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.cot' | sort > ELEMENTOS_LINEAS.txt
cont_elem=0
contador_total=0
aplic_old='A06' # the first app
while read fichero
       do
          aplic=$(cut -d "/" -f 4 $fichero) 
          aplic_act=$(cut -c1-3 $aplic | sort -u) # Aquí está el problema
          echo "$aplic_act"
          if [[ $aplic_act = $aplic_old  ]]; then
             ddconta_line=$(wc -l $fichero | awk '{ print $1 }')
             let contador_total=ddconta_line+contador_total
             let cont_elem=cont_elem+1
          else
            echo Numero de lineas de la aplicacion: $aplic_old  son: $contador_total
            contador_total=0

            ddconta_line2=$(wc -l $fichero | awk '{ print $1 }')
            let contador_total=ddconta_line2+contador_total
            let cont_elem=cont_elem+1
          fi
          aplic_old=$aplic_act
       done < ELEMENTOS_LINEAS.txt
```

El problema está en el corte. Necesito comparar la aplicación nueva con la aplicación antigua para guardar el número de líneas de esa aplicación y luego leer todos los elementos de la aplicación nueva para contar sus líneas.

El tema es que necesito conseguir sacar el número de líneas que tiene cada programa por aplicación (la aplicación son los 3 primeros caracteres del nombre del programa) el problema que tengo es en la linea del `aplic_act` en su declaración porque está fallando y me esta sacando algo raro, el contenido de mi home. Entonces no lo entiendo. ¿Podéis decirme cómo lo haríais vosotros?

¿Cuál podría ser la solución? ¿Qué pensais? Sé que es muy difícil, lo siento :(

Muchas gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que necsitas, tienes que contar cuantas líneas tiene la suma de los ficheros .cot agrupados por las 3 primeras líneas del nombre?

Comment: Sí exacto. para poder generar un informe con el numero de lineas que tiene cada aplicación, de ahi el if para compararlo

Answer (score 1):

Antes de responder: Cuando usas cut no estás operando sobre un string sino sobre el contenido de un archivo, no se usa como si fuera una especie de función substring.

Tú quieres comparar por aplicación y dices

> la aplicación son los 3 primeros caracteres del nombre del programa

De manera que voy a asumir que te da igual si están en los subdirectorios `/aplic/DSNI/` o `/aplic/SISI/`. Dado lo anterior, el nombre del archivo se puede obtener con:

```
fichero=/aplic/SISI/Z22P750Z.cot
nombre_archivo=${fichero##*/} 
echo "$nombre_archivo"
#escribe Z22P750Z.cot
```

Ahora que tienes el nombre del archivo, quieres los primeros 3 caracteres. Eso puedes hacerlo con:

```
aplic_act=`echo $nombre_archivo | sed -re 's/^(\w{3}).*$/\1/'`
```

Es decir, le pasas el texto "Z22P750Z.cot" al comando `sed` y ejecutas una expresión regular que captura los 3 primeros caracteres y descarta el resto.

Puedes probar lo anterior con:

```
find /aplic/DSNI/ /aplic/SISI/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.cot' | sort > ELEMENTOS_LINEAS.txt

while read fichero
       do
          nombre_archivo=${fichero##*/}
          aplic_act=`echo $nombre_archivo | sed -re 's/^(\w{3}).*$/\1/'`
          echo "nombre_archivo es $nombre_archivo y aplic_act es  $aplic_act"
       done < ELEMENTOS_LINEAS.txt
```

De ahí en adelante pienso que puedes meter el resto de tu lógica sin problemas